# Checkbox in gridview with Sqldatasource - How to insert Bit value in db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, checkbox

I am stuck with this. I have a gridview and a sqldatasource. I have created a footer row with a linkbutton to add records to MSSQL database.

[image]

I can insert all fileds except the last one, the checkbox, that is a BIT.
This is my event handler:

```
protected void lnkInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["name"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtName")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["username"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUsername")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["pass"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPass")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["uread"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUread")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["udownload"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUdownload")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["udelete"].DefaultValue =
        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUdelete")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["umail"].DefaultValue =
       ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUmail")).Text;

    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["is_admin"].DefaultValue =
        ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkCredential")).Checked;

    SqlDataSource1.Insert();

}
```

I have tried different version of the line about the checkbox, I even tried using Bool, Boolean, etc, but I cannot find the way to make it working.I keep getting errors like "impossible to convert bool in string". How should I write this line:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["is_admin"].DefaultValue =
        ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkCredential")).Checked;
```

Aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Admin" SortExpression="is_admin">
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("is_admin") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCredential" runat="server" />
       </FooterTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("is_admin") %>' Enabled="false" />
         </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

to make it working? Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: if checkedbox is checked then pass value 1 else 0.

Comment: @Anand ,what do you mean? How should I do that?

Comment: if((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkCredential")).Checked==true) then SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["is_admin"].DefaultValue=1; else 0

Comment: @Anand, impossible to convert int to string

Comment: if((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkCredential")).Checked==true) then SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["is_admin"].DefaultValue="1"; else "0"

Comment: @Anand, now it compiles but I have a cast exception. http://tinypic.com/r/35lzsyf/5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38310/discussion-between-anand-and-felicem)

Comment: @Anand, thanks a lot. Your support leaded to success. It is working now.

Comment: mark it as answer if it works for you.

Comment: post it as answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkCredential")).Checked==true) then SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["is_admin"].DefaultValue="1"; else "0"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["is_admin"].DefaultValue =
    ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("chkCredential")).Checked.ToString().ToLower();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but I get an invalid cast exception here:    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#....